# Spring AMQP handling intermittently fails after trying to call incorrect handler

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am performing integration tests between components communicating via Rabbitmq.
I have a consumer with this handler method:

```
@RabbitHandler
public List<Call> handle(CallRecordMonthRequest request){
    return source.getCalls(request.getMonth(), request.getYear());
}
```

However, sometimes when the consumer attempts to handle a message, it fails with the following exception:

> org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.exception.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Failed to invoke target method 'handle' with argument type = [class [B], value = [{[B@7d202207}]
>       ...
>       ...
>       ...
>       Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.rainn.reporting.communication.RabbitMqAdapter.handle([B)

I added a handler which takes a `byte[]` and when I turn it into a string, it is the same json payload that is mean to be deserialized into the proper type.

Answer (score 0):

It probably means the errant messages do not have a `contentType` property. The `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` will return any message that does not have a content type (or has one that does not contain the string `json`) as a `byte[]`.

Messages should normally have a `contentType` of `application/json`.

If you can't fix the sender, you can subclass the converter, and override `fromMessage` as follows...

```
public Object fromMessage(Message message, Object conversionHint) throws MessageConversionException {
    MessageProperties properties = message.getMessageProperties();
    if (properties.getContentType == null) {
        properties.setContentType("application/json");
    }
    super.fromMessage(message, conversionHint);
}
```